# EF migrations not working in Github action, same command works locally

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, github-actions, entity-framework-migrations

I can run the following command locally to update my DB using Entity Framework Core migrations:

`dotnet ef database update 0 --project src\MyProject\MyProject.csproj --startup-project src\MyStartupProject\MyStartupProject.csproj --context MyDbContext`

However when I try to run it in a GitHub action I get an error.

The action:

```
name: Migrate DB
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Check out repository code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Migrate DB
        shell: pwsh
        run: |
          dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
          dotnet tool restore

          dotnet ef database update 0 --project src\MyProject\MyProject.csproj --startup-project src\MyStartupProject\MyStartupProject.csproj --context MyDbContext
```

The error is:

> /home/runner/work/MyProject/MyProject/src/MyProject/MyProject.csproj :
> error MSB4057: The target "GetEFProjectMetadata" does not exist in the
> project. Unable to retrieve project metadata. Ensure it's an SDK-style
> project. If you're using a custom BaseIntermediateOutputPath or
> MSBuildProjectExtensionsPath values, Use the
> --msbuildprojectextensionspath option.

As far as I know I'm not using a custom BaseIntermediateOutputPath or MSBuildProjectExtensionsPath values. The projects are a `dotnet 6` web project and class library built in `C#`.

I've tried adding `--msbuildprojectextensionspath` with the value `obj/local` as suggested in similar questions but it has had no effect.

Comment: Very strange. Does adding `--verbose` provide any more clues?

Comment: Found this issue - see my answer below - I hadn't built the project in the pipeline and the obj folder was therefore missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bit of a face-palm. It turns out it was because I was not first building the project in the pipeline which meant that the git ignored items were not there. I assume the issue was the missing `obj` folder.

The solution was to use `dotnet-ef` instead of `dotnet ef` which builds the project before attempting migrations (although I assume that simple running `dotnet build` beforehand may have also worked).

```
dotnet-ef database update 0 --project src\MyProject\MyProject.csproj --startup-project src\MyStartupProject\MyStartupProject.csproj --context MyDbContext
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of adding this command in your github yml file you can migrate database in your program class:

in new program class (ASP .NET 6):

```
using var scope = app.Services.CreateScope();

using var appContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();

appContext.Database.Migrate();
```

in classic program class:

```
var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();

using var scope = host.Services.CreateScope();
var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
var context = services.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
context.Database.Migrate();

await host.RunAsync();
```

it will migrate if your database it's not up to date.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestions that but I would rather use the commands, Microsoft recommends against using this method in a production environment. My final plan will be to use the commands to generate sql scripts and then run those but I imagine I will encounter the same issue with the cli.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, it was working locally but not on an Azure DevOps Agent.

The agent was Ubuntu, thus after changing paths from `\` to `/` it was then the working fine.