# Entity Framework Core can't create a migration

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm encountering an issue when trying to run an Entity Framework Core migration (`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` 8.0.1).

The error is:

> Error MSB4057: The target "GetEFProjectMetadata" does not exist in the project. Unable to retrieve project metadata. Ensure it's an MSBuild-based .NET Core project. If you're using custom BaseIntermediateOutputPath or MSBuildProjectExtensionsPath values, Use the --msbuildprojectextensionspath option.

I've run migrations successfully before with the same configuration, and the only changes I made were to my entity classes; I haven't modified any path values.

The command I'm using to run the migration is:

```
dotnet ef migrations add CustomerEntityUpdate -p X -s Y
```

Comment: Shere your project structure and how did you exectued the the command and which projected you were pointed to? Which IDE you are using? If you are in visual studio you could try this `Add-Migration CustomerEntityUpdate ` as well.

Comment: please check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73051523/ef-migrations-not-working-in-github-action-same-command-works-locally